# Numpy Dot product with nested array

Tags: python, numpy

trying to come up with a method to perform load combinations and transient load patterning for structural/civil engineering applications.

without patterning it's fairly simple:

```
list of load results = [[d],[t1],...,[ti]], where [ti] = transient load result as a numpy array = A

list of combos = [[1,0,....,0],[0,1,....,1], [dfi, tf1,.....,tfi]] , where tfi = code load factor for transient load = B
```

in python this works as `numpy.dot(A,B)`

so my issue arises where:

```
`list of load results = [[d],[t1],.....[ti]]`, where [t1] = [[t11]......[t1i]] for i pattern possibilities and [t1i] = numpy array
```

so I have a nested array within another array and want to multiply by a matrix of load combinations. Is there a way to implement this in one matrix operation, I can come up with a method by looping the pattern possibilities then a dot product with the load combos, but this is computationally expensive. Any thoughts?

Thanks

for an example not considering patterning see: https://github.com/buddyd16/Structural-Engineering/blob/master/Analysis/load_combo_test.py

essential I need a method that gives similar results assuming that for `loads = np.array([[D],[Ex],[Ey],[F],[H],[L],[Lr],[R],[S],[Wx],[Wy]])` --> `[L],[Lr],[R],[S]` are actually nested arrays ie if D = 1x500 array/vector, L, Lr, R, or S could = 100x500 array.

my simple solution is:

```
combined_pattern = []
for pattern in load_patterns:
    loads = np.array([[D],[Ex],[Ey],[F],[H],[L[pattern]],[Lr[pattern]],[R[pattern]],[S[pattern]],[Wx],[Wy]])
    combined_pattern.append(np.dot(basic_factors, loads))
```

Simpler Example:

```
import numpy as np

#Simple

A = np.array([1,0,0])
B = np.array([0,1,0])
C = np.array([0,0,1])

Loads = np.array([A,B,C])

Factors = np.array([[1,1,1],[0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.25,0.25,0.25]])

result = np.dot(Factors, Loads)

# Looking for a faster way to accomplish the below operation   
# this works but will be slow for large data sets
# bi can be up to 1x5000 in size and i can be up to 500

A = np.array([1,0,0])
b1 = np.array([1,0,0])
b2 = np.array([0,1,0])
b3 = np.array([0,0,1])
B = np.array([b1,b2,b3])
C = np.array([0,0,1])

result_list = []

for load in B:
    Loads = np.array([A,load,C])

    Factors = np.array([[1,1,1],[0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.25,0.25,0.25]])

    result = np.dot(Factors, Loads)

    result_list.append(result)
```

edit: Had Factors and Loads reversed in the np.dot().

Comment: I would add another dimension to the array and use numpy's broadcasting. The additional dimension is what your for loop would iterate along.

Comment: http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'nested array'.  One possibility is that it is a multidimensional array - 2, 3 or more dimensions.  There are tools for doing `dot` with those - `einsum`, `tensordot` and `matmul` (`@`).  The other possibility is that the array has object dtype, with pointers to arrays (of possibly differing shapes).  Such an array is, for many purposes, a list of arrays.

Comment: I edited my questions to include a simpler example of what I'm trying to accomplish.
@hpaulj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple example, the array shapes are:

```
In [2]: A.shape
Out[2]: (3,)
In [3]: Loads.shape
Out[3]: (3, 3)
In [4]: Factors.shape
Out[4]: (3, 3)
In [5]: result.shape
Out[5]: (3, 3)
```

The rule in `dot` is that the last dimension of `Loads` pairs with the 2nd to the last of `Factors`

```
result = np.dot(Loads,Factors)
(3,3) dot (3,3) => (3,3)    # 3's in common
(m,n) dot (n,l) => (m,l)    # n's in common
```

In the iteration, `A`,`load` and `C` are all (3,) and `Loads` is (3,3).

`result_list` is a list of 3 (3,3) arrays, and `np.array(result_list)` would be (3,3,3).

Let's make a 3d array of all the `Loads`:

```
In [16]: Bloads = np.array([np.array([A,load,C]) for load in B])
In [17]: Bloads.shape
Out[17]: (3, 3, 3)
In [18]: Bloads
Out[18]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1]]])
```

I can easily do a `dot` of this `Bloads` and `Factors` with `einsum`:

```
In [19]: np.einsum('lkm,mn->lkn', Bloads, Factors)
Out[19]: 
array([[[1.  , 1.  , 1.  ],
        [1.  , 1.  , 1.  ],
        [0.25, 0.25, 0.25]],

       [[1.  , 1.  , 1.  ],
        [0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 ],
        [0.25, 0.25, 0.25]],

       [[1.  , 1.  , 1.  ],
        [0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
        [0.25, 0.25, 0.25]]])
```

`einsum` isn't the only way, but it's the easiest way (for me) to keep track of dimensions.

It's even easier to keep dimensions straight if they differ.  Here they are all 3, so it's hard to keep them separate.  But if `B` was (5,4) and `Factors` (4,2), then `Bloads` would be (5,3,4), and the `einsum` result (5,3,2) (the size 4 dropping out in the `dot`).

Constructing `Bloads` without a loop is a bit trickier, since the rows of `B` are interleaved with `A` and `C`.

```
In [38]: np.stack((A[None,:].repeat(3,0),B,C[None,:].repeat(3,0)),1)
Out[38]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1]]])
```

To understand this test the subexpressions, e.g. `A[None,:]`, the `repeat` etc.

Equivalently:

```
np.array((A[None,:].repeat(3,0),B,C[None,:].repeat(3,0))).transpose(1,0,2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.